How do i make the day on the day cell in Month view focusable?
So in this demo here the day on the day cell is focusbale (https://fullcalendar.io/demos)
But in this example (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/month-view-demo) it is not, not sure it is because the version diff there's some changes in the implementation ?
I tried looking at the docs and also inspected the code, there is a tabindex="0" on the fc-daygrid-day-top date this example (https://fullcalendar.io/demos) but none on this (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/month-view-demo)

It's because in the first demo, the day numbers are clickable. Enabling that creates a hyperlink with the tabindex on it.
By default in fullCalendar 6 these clickable navigation links are not enabled and for the day text it will render something like
<a aria-label="October 2, 2024" id="fc-dom-8" class="fc-daygrid-day-number">2</a>

to display the day.
But if you set
navLinks: true

in the calendar options then it makes the day numbers clickable (it will take you to the specific view for that day if you click one) and thus they become something useful to focus on, so it adds the tabindex, among other things:
<a title="Go to October 2, 2024" data-navlink="" tabindex="0" id="fc-dom-8" class="fc-daygrid-day-number">2</a>

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dyxNyyj
See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/navLinks for more info.
